# MySQL How to Avoid Duplicate Entries from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates, unique

I thought the most efficient way was to create a `UNIQUE` field on the table instead of selecting to check for existing values before doing anything else but this makes use of two queries. Instead with a `UNIQUE` field only one query is necessary because MySQL checks for you. The problem is that duplicate entry errors cause an internal server error which I cannot recover from in PHP. What do you guys suggest, what is the best way to avoid duplicate entries in a PHP & MySQL application?

Comment: It is better to check and confirm for duplicacy before you run your  insert query

Comment: @nedstark Wouldn't it be better with a `UNIQUE` constraint, faster?

Comment: "The problem is that duplicate entry errors cause an internal server error which I cannot recover from in PHP" that sounds odd, please explain

Comment: @Dagon exactly how it sounds, I am using CodeIgniter btw. Every time I try to insert the same information already in a field with a `UNIQUE` constraint, for testing, I get in return an internal server error `500`. I have tried `try/catch` blocks but the program just stops execution...

Comment: theres going to be some error message somewhere, find it.

Comment: @Dagon I have asked why it does this in two other threads and no one has been able to help. There are no errors logged in WAMP, in Firebug I just get a 500 error and nothing more and it only happens when a duplicate entry error occurs.

Comment: internal server error 500 is returned because there is error in your mysql query due to duplicacy , so before executing query you need to confirm that you are not entering any duplicate data by running other query

Comment: @nedstark I think this could be avoided if the duplicate query didn't throw a 500 error. I think Dagon knows this can be avoided.

Comment: Look at your log file on the server and see what it tells you about accessing the file.

Comment: @Skewled Nothing is being logged, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

> INSERT INTO someTable (id, amount) VALUES ($to_uid, $send_amount) 
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + $send_amount

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

2) You can catch the duplicate key exception. PDO example:

```
try{
    $stmt->execute(...);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062){
        // Mysql returned 1062 error code which means a duplicate key
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but what about mysqli or CodeIgniter which is what I am using? A plain try/catch does not work.

Comment: Because `mysqli` doesn't throw exceptions by default. `Mysqli` functions just return false. See this answer if you want make mysqli throw exceptions on error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli Or just check `mysqli::$errno` for 1062 code when   for example `mysqli::query` returns false

Comment: Guess I will be asking how to do this in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use REPLACE INTO for your query, it will try an insert first and than it will delete the row with the same ID and replace it.

Comment: That is not what I want. I do not want to replace anything I just want to avoid putting in information that is already there. You said duplicate errors could not be recovered from, I think Dagon has a different idea.

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION!**

CodeIgniter requires the setting

```
$db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE;
```

an explicitly calling

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

In order for MySQL to throw exceptions. The exceptions must also be caught.

Comment: I mentioned about `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` in my answer comments. Cool guy did his answer. Great

Comment: @Didar_Uranov I thank you for your help but this was actually more a of a CodeIgniter issue which you failed to resolve. Without the setting I mentioned MySQL would not have been able to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to prevent updating a row and prevent an exception from being thrown if row already exists.

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
>
> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error occurs. Ignored
>   errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do
>   not.